# Can't access to web server in my internal network from smartphone?

Tags: android, iis, networking, server, network-protocols

I have one IIS server running in my internal network and when I want to have access to my server from a computer inside my network I just type the hostname in the browser and i am automatically redirected to it.

Although, if i try to access it from android mobile phone or ubuntu computer I am not able to access it.

Why is this happening? Shouldn't it be the same? I mean, they are all browsers and http requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to certificates, needed to configure the iis server the right way in order to acess it.

Answer (score 0):

The important thing to understand is that names don't mean much in networking and everything is base don IP addresses.  "Something" has to translate a computer name to its IP address.

Some background:
IIS means you are running on Windows and since you are at home I don't think you are running a domain server but more likely in Workgroup mode.  If all of this is correct then Windows name server will only look for Windows-based pcs.  This means that a Linux or Android box won't know how to translate the name you are asking for to its IP address on the network.

You will have to look for software that can be added to your Windows' box to handle the translation request from Linxu/Android.

A quick and easy fix is to call it by its IP address instead of its name.  To find out the IP address on your Windows box:  Start -> Run (or hold the Windows key and hit R) and type in CMD then hit the return key.  Now type in ipconfig and hit the return key.  You will see your IP address in there.  It will be most likely listed as IPv4 address.  Type in the IP address in the browser on your Linux box or your Android device and it should work.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have tried that but when i use bridged mode i should have the VM machine name appear under my local network group. and it doesnt appear. I cant have access to it. if i add the ip and the hostname to the host file i can have acecss to it. but not in any other way

Answer (score -2):

On windows you use 127.0.0.1 but on Android Phone you should use 10.0.2.2..

Comment: But the server is not running in my android Phone. It is running in a windows computer